# Rewriting a function in specific terms with Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, expression, simplify, mupad

I feel there should be an easy solution to my problem but I couldn't find it.

I can explain my problem through a very simple example:
Given the functions f and a:

```
f := x(x-3) + 2x(x-3)
a := (x-3)
```

I now want to write f in terms of a which should be:

```
f = (x + 2x)a
or
f = 3xa
```

This is a very easy example, what I eventually want to do includes integrations of volumes.

I did find Mupad functions "Simplify" and "Rewrite" but I do not believe they can do what I want here. Is there a function in Matlab or a procedure that can do this automatically?

Comment: Not really familiar with this, but if you just want to get `a` 'outside the brackets', perhaps just divide by `a`? I doubt whether there is any functionality to extract all occurances of `a` (As it may occur in many different ways simultaneously).

Comment: Do you have the Symbolic Toolbox?

Comment: I am not yet familiar with the Symbolic Toolbox but it seems to be included at the Matlab installation at our University's computers.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to substitute for ONLY some of the x elements in the expression? How do you expect a computer to know what you want? Computers are quite literal things. If you tell it that

```
a = x - 3
```

then it must also know that

```
x = a + 3
```

Therefore,

```
f = (a+3)a + 2(a+3)a = 3a(a+3)
```

Only a computer that can read your mind will know that you wish to replace only some of the terms.

Comment: I am sorry, my example was not the best. It doesn't really matter how the a term in my example is implemented in f, as long as it is there. (preferably in a "clean" way, it is to make the formula of f more easy to understand)
I could try and give the original problem in my question, that will make my question probably better to understand.